# Validate field only if the user doing the save has a certain role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, authorization

In my Rails app I have a model attribute that only administrators are permitted to edit. For admins, the field must be present and valid.

However in testing with a non-admin user, saving the model fails because it says the value for the field is invalid.

I don't want to remove presence validation or allow_blank, because that's actually invalid for the admin user.

How can I have a validation that applies to only a certain role of user?

**Update:**

Essentiality what I'm looking for is described in [Section 5.4 of the Rails Guide for Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#grouping-conditional-validations), however the Section 5.3 and 5.4 assume I'm do I save on the `User` model, right?

I'm actually trying to allow users to edit any model in my app, but only some fields are available to be saved by *admins*.

To add more context. To prevent non-admins saving attributes they're not permitted to, I have different [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) set depending on the user's role type.. so the fields I'm concerned about aren't even hitting the model, which is why validations are now complaining.

Conceptually, what I'm looking for is, instead of the following as shown in Sec 5.4 of the guide which shows a user editing **their** user record:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  with_options if: :is_admin? do |admin|
    admin.validates :password, length: { minimum: 10 }
    admin.validates :email, presence: true
  end
end
```

what I need is

```
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  with_options if: current_user.is_admin? do |admin|
    admin.validates :color, presence: true
  end
end
```

In this example, only admins can edit the color of an appointment, but if the user **is** an admin, it **must** be present and valid.

Comment: It doesn't feel right, but as a hack I could pass the `role` identifier of the user saving every for so I have a way to tell. I'd then have to protect against the user hacking themselves to a higher permission level too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `validate` with `if: Proc.new { }`

Some thing like this should do -

`validate :validation_method, if: Proc.new { |user| user.has_role?(admin) }`

Comment: Would that also work on models other than the user model?

Answer (score 0):

I've decided I should keep the models uncoupled from the controller, keeping their responsibilities distinct.

The implementation option I've chosen is: If the model needs to know something about the user, the controller should tell it.

1. To the models I've added `attr_accessor :modifier_is_admin`
2. In the appropriate model validations, I've added `if: lambda { obj.modifier_is_admin }`
3. In all controllers that call `create` or `update`, they merge in attribute `modifier_is_admin: current_user.admin?`